# AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'stream'

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking at reading information from firestore. So I followed the examples from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py). Here is my code. It's a Flask application which calls the firestore client.

```
@menuapi_routes.route("/api/menu")
def get_menus():
    menu_items = get_menu_items()
    retval = []
    for item in menu_items.stream():
        retval.append(u' {} => {}'.format(item.id, item.to_dict()))
    return json.dumps(retval)
```

The code which is getting called is.

```
def get_menu_items():
    db = firestore.Client()
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'menus')
    return doc_ref
```

The error I get is

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 22:09:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2020-05-16 22:09:34,236] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/menu [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "\app\api\menu\menu.py", line 13, in get_menus
    for item in menu_items.stream():
AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'stream'
Exception on /api/menu [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "\app\api\menu\menu.py", line 13, in get_menus
    for item in menu_items.stream():
AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'stream'
Exception on /api/menu [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "\app\api\menu\menu.py", line 13, in get_menus
    for item in menu_items.stream():
AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'stream'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 22:09:34] "GET /api/menu HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: That db has a `menus` collection? since I can see it has a `museums ` collection?

Comment: Not sure where you see a museum collection.

Comment: in the above link you put in your question

Comment: I have adapted the code in the link. But my collection name is different.

Comment: OK, then you have `menus` ?

Comment: Yes I do have `menus` collection

Comment: The error says you are trying to stream a collection. but stream is for documents according to `https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_2`. So there should be another level of collection maybe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214001/discussion-between-ehsan-and-vinay-joseph).